# Failure to make a post request to RESTful API using HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I've been trying to make a POST request to send a group chat message using the Trillian API https://trillian.im/help/api/v2/#send-a-message-to-a-group-chat

It works to make a POST request using `HttpWebRequest`, for which I've included the working code. What I want is to be able to make a POST request using the `HttpClient`.

I cannot seem to be able to put together a method that uses `HttpClient` to make that POST. I just end up getting the 401 error which means the API token is invalid, but it is absolutely valid because it works with `HttpWebRequest`.

One thing to note is that I have an additional class `ApiHelper` that I'm using with `HttpClient` so that I can reuse one `HttpClient` in the application (idea from Tim Corey: https://youtu.be/aWePkE2ReGw?t=367).

I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure out how to put together a working method that uses `HttpClient` to make a POST request with the Trillian API.

`ApiHelper` class for `HttpClient`:

```
public static class ApiHelper
{
    public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }

    public static void InitializeClient()
    {
        ApiClient = new HttpClient();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}
```

BROKEN code using `HttpClient`

```
public static void HttpClientPOST()
{
    //%23 is an encoded #
    string groupID = "%23groupChatIDHere";
    string url = "https://impp.name.net/v2/name.net/groupchats/" + groupID + "/messages/";

    string fromParam = "trillian@name.net";
    string messageParam = "test message";
    string urlTokenParam = "tokenCodeHere";

    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    parameters.Add("from", fromParam);
    parameters.Add("message", messageParam);
    parameters.Add("token", urlTokenParam);

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
    ApiHelper.ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    var task = Task.Run(() => ApiHelper.ApiClient.PostAsync(ApiHelper.ApiClient.BaseAddress, content));
    task.Wait();
    var response = task.Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var success = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

WORKING code using `HttpWebRequest`

```
public static int HttpWebRequestPOST()
{
    //%23 is an encoded #
    string groupID = "%23groupChatIDHere";
    string Url = "https://impp.name.net/v2/name.net/groupchats/" + groupID + "/messages/";

    //Start the creation of the web API request as a POST method
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    request.Method = "POST";

    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

    string fromParam = "from=trillian%40name.net";
    string messageParam = "&message=test message";
    string urlTokenParam = "&token=tokenCodeHere";


    //Encode the information to be able to send the call to API
    Byte[] byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(fromParam + messageParam + urlTokenParam);

    //Set the content type to allow paramaters to be passed via URL
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    long length = 0;
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {

            length = response.ContentLength;

            return Convert.ToInt32(response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(errorResponse.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: You don't need to do `Task.Run`. You can just do `var response = ApiHelper.ApiClient.PostAsync(...).Result`.

Comment: Also, your `ApiClient` is subject to race conditions. What happens when two or more processes are simultaneously making requests to two different URLs? The `BaseAddress` property could get changed between the time you set it and the time you execute the request.

Comment: To that point, you don't even need to set the BaseAddress here since you're passing the entire URL into PostAsync anyways. That's actually probably causing an issue

Comment: Not a stupid question because it can happen. I just verified it with and without the suggested adjustments. The token is 100% exactly the same. I will look into information about race conditions, but I can guarantee that it is the only request with HttpClient in the program.